# mongodb with microsoft failover cluster

Tags: mongodb, failovercluster

im required to install mongodb in a microsoft windows 2012r2 server in a failover cluster mode.
does mongodb supports that as microsoft sql do?
if the answer is yes, can you point mo to a guide please?

thanks!
Guy

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The technology in MongoDB is called [Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/). You define several servers to act in unison as a *Replica Set*; they automatically keep identical copies of the same data, and if the *primary* fails then the replica set will automatically fail over: one of the other nodes will take over as the new primary.